# Costs of tour in Kyrgyzstan

Tags: tours, guides, kyrgyzstan, central-asia

Though I have some experience with travelling/backpacking through Asia (India, Nepal, East-Asia) this year will be the first time I visit a country like Kyrgyzstan and will also be the first time I want to arrange a tour before the trip starts.

I've already contacted I few companies that organizes tours in/around Kyrgyzstan, of which one already mailed me a program with calculated costs ([Click to see](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-xv4QkMgbxSW5TcWtNMl8zZkdBV1Bnbm5rcm1taXRic3ln/edit?pli=1)). Though I have the feeling the costs are a bit high (especially the stuff not included), I actually have no idea what is normal in Kyrgyzstan and like to hear your opinion on this. Also; how flexible are tour operators in Kyrgyzstan to just book a tour after arrival in Bishkek? We are staying for ~18 days.

Comment: Just an FYI, it is possible to explore Kyrgyzstan on your own.  I did it on my first time there, and only met one person who went on a tour.  Saying that, her tour sounded AMAZING.

Comment: If you hop into the chat and flag me, I can give you some advice.  I won't be back on for a couple of hours tho.